# Test NestJS Controller and Service without Mocking - Prisma & SQLite

Tags: nestjs, prisma

This maybe a biased opinion, but I hate mocking. I would rather use SQLite to have minimum mocking required. Is there a way that I can use MySQL in dev/prod environment and SQLite for testing. I am unable switch between the databases.

I added a Test Prisma Service to use SQLite,

```js
@Injectable()
export class PrismaServiceTest
  extends PrismaClient<
    Prisma.PrismaClientOptions,
    'query' | 'error' | 'beforeExit'
  >
  implements OnModuleInit
{
  constructor() {
    super({
      datasources: {
        db: {
          // I can't change the provider here
          url: 'file:../../prisma/test.db',
        },
      },
    });
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}
```

Then,

```js
describe('UserController', () => {
  let service: UserService;
  let controller: UserController;
  let prisma: DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [GlobalModule],
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [UserService, PrismaService],
    })
      .overrideProvider(PrismaService)
      .useValue(new PrismaServiceTest())
      .compile();

    service = module.get(UserService);
    controller = module.get(UserController);
    prisma = module.get(PrismaServiceTest);
  });

  it('signup user', async () => {
    const user = await controller.createUser(signupUser);
    expect(user.email).toEqual(signupUser.email);
  });
});
```

Since I am not able to change the provider, its looking for MySQL connection string. Is there an easy to switch between SQLite and MySQL?

[image]

---

This is what I consider as useless mocking. If you are going to mock everything, then what are you testing really...? Plus, you can save a lot of time by using SQLite instead.

```js
const uselessPrismaMocks = {
    user: { findMany: () => Promise.resolve({}) },
};

describe('UserController', () => {
  let service: UserService;
  let controller: UserController;
  let prisma: DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [GlobalModule],
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [UserService, PrismaService],
    })
      .overrideProvider(PrismaService)
      .useValue(uselessPrismaMocks)
      .compile();

    service = module.get(UserService);
    controller = module.get(UserController);
    prisma = module.get(PrismaServiceTest);
  });

  it('signup user', async () => {
    const user = await controller.createUser(signupUser);
    expect(user.email).toEqual(signupUser.email);
  });
});
```

Comment: can you use `env` variable?

Comment: Prisma doesn't allow you to use env for providers, only for connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding `PrismaService` to the `providers` array, why not use a custom provider that your `overrideProvider` is already *trying* to do:

```js
describe('UserController', () => {
  let service: UserService;
  let controller: UserController;
  let prisma: DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [GlobalModule],
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [
        UserService,
        {
          provide: PrismaService,
          useClass: PrismaServiceTest,
        },
      ],
    })
      .compile();

    service = module.get(UserService);
    controller = module.get(UserController);
    prisma = module.get(PrismaServiceTest);
  });

  it('signup user', async () => {
    const user = await controller.createUser(signupUser);
    expect(user.email).toEqual(signupUser.email);
  });
});
```

The `overrideProvider` is better for providers that get created by modules *imported* by the `Test.createTestingModule`. As you have full control of the providers given directly to the `createTestingModule`, make use of the [custom providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#custom-providers-1) so you can take advantage of changing what is provided for specific tokens.

Comment: Still getting the same issue. This does not solve the issue of switching between SQLite and MySQL. As you mentioned, isn't `overrideProvider` doing the same thing as `useClass`? I will look into `useClass` further. Either way, this will not resolve the issue, because it is expecting MySQL connection string, as this is what I am using for development.

Comment: That specifically looks like an issue with how the prisma.schema file is set up, expecting the protocol and database to be mysql instead of sqlite. From [what I can tell in the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#datasources) you should be able to swap providers **but** you have to generate a new PrismaClient each time by changing the schema file, running the generate, *then* running your tests

Comment: Yea. I went down this path as well earlier. I get stuck at `enums`, since SQLite doesn't support it. Typically ORMs do a quick swap to string in this case. But even if I swap enums manually, when I re-install the prisma client it throws missing enum types error on compile. I don't know how to bypass this type error. If I manually update the package in `node_modules`, I won't be able to automate this through github actions.

Comment: What baffles me that the amount of people that are using Prisma, and none of them thought that mocking is a waste of time, we should use SQLite instead.

Comment: Most people don't think mocking is a waste of time. I'd even argue that using a database _other than what you plan to use_ is an even bigger waste of time. If you want to test against a controlled environment, spin up a docker container and change the env variables to point to that rather than your usual dev database

Comment: Lol what! What are you going to do with the constraints??? You will have to mock those!!!

Comment: You should only mock the external services, not internal services!

Comment: And it can be argued that the database and orm are external to your logic, so it _would_ make sense to mock them. You don't have to agree, just sharing a perspective. Docker containers are what you'll be looking for here, not swapping out database types

Comment: Spining up a database is not an issue, but the constraints are!

Comment: Sure, I agree that Prisma can be consider as an external service. I give you that. But if you start mocking, then where will it end? You will have to either add all the constraints or mock them. Either way you are spending more time in writing mocks/constraints than actual testing and development.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that spinning up a database is a solution here. But please correct me if I am missing something.